# Equivalence of Sobolev spaces $H^{k,p}$ and $W^{k,p}$ in the case $p=1$ or $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

It is well known that $H^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)=W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ if $p \in (1, \infty)$ and $k$ is a non-negative integer.

Here, $H^{s,p}=\{f \in \mathcal{S}' \mid \| f \|_{H^{s,p}}:= \|(1-\Delta)^{s/2}f\|_{L^p} < \infty\}$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p \in [1, \infty]$.

However, what do we know about the relationship between $H^{k,1}$ and $W^{k,1}$, or $H^{k,\infty}$ and $W^{k, \infty}$ ?

Comment: I think I remember a math.SE post listing something related with quotations from Stein's Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties Of Functions book

Comment: I cannot recall Stein's notation exactly and I cannot find the post that I mentioned, so let me just comment Stein's page 161 may be relevant

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you for your very helpful comment. I'm poor at English, and so I appreciate you editing the title of this question.